# No module named bs4

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to use beautifulsoup on Windows 10 but am running into an error every time I run the code, 'no module named bs4.' I've tried pip, pip3, and easy_install for both beautifulsoup4 and bs4 but it still won't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide info about your OS system and the version of the package you are using. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your PYTHONPATH is set incorrectly, or is missing paths that should be there. You don't mention your platform, but there are a number of different questions revolving around this:

- [Fixing a broken PYTHONPATH environment variable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206862/fixing-a-broken-pythonpath-environment-variable)
- [How to fix the python path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9320305/how-to-fix-the-python-path)
- [Pythonpath is still ignored and unable to install locally with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11895233/pythonpath-is-still-ignored-and-unable-to-install-locally-with-pip)

Depending on your platform and setup, there might be a number of different ways of fixing this.

You might also consider using a tool such as [pipenv](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv) to manage "virtual environments" for your different projects, which can be helpful when dependencies clash.

Comment: @Wxsko glad i could help. I would appreciate if you marked my answer as having answered your question. You can do that on the checkmark to the left of it :)